# set custom ringtone to specific contact number in Android 7

Tags: android, sql-update, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-7.1-nougat

> how can I set a ringtone for a specific contact?

```
int result =  getContentResolver().update(contactUri, ContentValues, null, null);
```

> result = 1
>   but custom ringtone is not updating in android 7 or above

Comment: what are you putting in `ContentValues`?

Comment: contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE,
                            audioUri.toString());